# SQL Server : sorting a distinct table which has XML column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table which I need to do a distinct on as it has some duplicates and then needs to sort it and join the XML into one column.

Here is what I tried :

```
Select * 
From TableA
Where TableID ='1234'
  And Convert(nvarchar(max), xmlcolumn) in (Select Distinct Convert(nvarchar(max), xmlcolumn))
```

The above does sort out the list for me nor it removes the duplicates.

```
Select distinct convert (nvarchar(max), xmlcolumn)
From TableA
Where TableID ='1234'
Order By TableID
```

The above returns what is required, but if I do an order by (as shown above) I get an error:

> ORDER by items must appear in the select list if select district is specified

I don't want to enter the `TableID` in the select statement because I don't want this in the results. Secondly, how do I convert the XML (which is converted to `nvarchar` to do the distinct) back to XML for exporting to C#.

Comment: Why do you need `Order by TableId` when all `TableId = '1234'`

Comment: THe table contain's lots of data which I can select with TableID. SO table ID 1234 for e.g. contains 600 entries, which I need to extract the XMLcolumn

Comment: `Order by` doesn't change the quantity of rows that you take. 
It just orders the result set by a specified column list.
The error message is very clear, if you use `distinct` keyword, then all columns in `order by` clause 
must be existent in your selected columns.
In your case, just remove `Order by TableId` or change it to `Order by anyselectedcolumn`

Comment: I need to order by a column which I don't need in the results. E.g. Column A, XML Column, Column B. Now column a has a number 1234 the rows for which are shared by COlumn B and XML column respectively. Now I need to select by 1234 do a distinct as there are duplicates I can see. Then order the XML column and export to C#. I can only order XML by ColumnA or ColumnB. But I don't need these columns in the results. I hope I'm clear enough

Comment: Can someone remove the downvote please. This is a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you could remove duplicate rows by using `ROW_NUMBER` like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    TableID varchar(10),
    ColumnA int,
    ColumnB varchar(10),
    XmlColumn xml   
)

;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT sd.TableID,
           CAST(sd.XmlColumn AS nvarchar(max)) AS XmlColumn,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(sd.XmlColumn AS nvarchar(max)) ORDER BY sd.TableID) AS Rn
    FROM @SampleData sd 
    Where TableID = '1234' 
)
SELECT t.XmlColumn 
FROM temp t
WHERE Rn = 1 -- remove duplicate rows
ORDER BY t.TableID -- order by any columns
```

Comment: This query works but it has to be modified a little. Here you are doing a CTE and selecting from that CTE itself, so the result is empty. I copied this query and in the select query right after th CTE i modified the select to point to my original table I need to fetch table from. So it work's. Hence +1 and accepting the answer. Thanks, and sorry for the late reply as was out of town.

Comment: I didn't understand RN concept, would you mind explaining that briefly how does the RN help to get rid of the duplicate's.

Comment: You could read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql. `PARTITION BY` means group by `XmlColumn`, then you only take the first row (Rn = 1) in this group. Of course, it will be unique for each `XmlColumn`

Comment: THank you @TriV, it's much appreciated.